# Textfield Autocomplete

Tags: sql, autocomplete, oracle-apex

I´m using the Apex item **Textfield with Autocomplete**, loading the result list using a simple SQL query. I noticed that, if i impose a limit to the size of the list, while i am typing the search string, the list stops showing, even if the query still brings valid results. This occurs with the **Lazy Loading option** turned off.

SQL code:

```
select PESS_NM from (
SELECT P.PESS_CD,
  P.PESS_DV,
  P.PESS_NM,
  P.PESS_CEFT_CD,
  C.CEFT_DS
FROM SP.PESSOAL P, SP.CAREFETIVO C
WHERE P.PESS_CEFT_CD = C.CEFT_CD
) where (
 instr(upper("PESS_NM"),upper(nvl(:P164_NOME_PARTICIPANTE,"PESS_NM"))) > 0 )
```

[image: Textfield Autocomplete properties on Page Designer]

I tried to use a large limit (999).
The table holds a fair amount of records (near 20000).
The moment i removed the limit to the number of itens on the list, everything works fine.

What´s the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be including the where-clause. `instr(upper("PESS_NM"),upper(nvl(:P164_NOME_PARTICIPANTE,"PESS_NM"))) > 0 )`

Apex will by itself filter on the values (likely, it'll wrap your query in an inner query and then add a where clause itself). By adding in this where-clause you're setting yourself up for problems as the item itself will not constantly be brought to session state. The list you provide should be the full list (unless there are parent items which should limit selection).

Eg:

```
SELECT P.PESS_NM
FROM SP.PESSOAL P, SP.CAREFETIVO C
WHERE P.PESS_CEFT_CD = C.CEFT_CD
```